# Worthwhile transmutes from prospecting

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a couple of toons in WoW, one of which is a jewelcrafter and the other is an alchemist. my jewelcrafter often when prospecting and looking for valuable gems such as Inferno Ruby's will also create a bunch of gems I don't have much use for such as the following:

- Carnelian
- Hessonite
- Zephyrite
- Amber Jewel
- Ocean Sapphire
- Ember Topaz

Curious enough - is there anything useful I can do besides just sell these in the auction house with my alchemists transmute skill? By useful, I mean turn them into something with potentially worth more. I do realize that "worth more" is variable to the economy on a particular server and the whole supply vs demand requirements are always in place. I'm looking for more generic guidance though. What do you usually do with these additional gems that I'd otherwise do nothing with and throw away in the AH and hope someone clicks buy on them?

The Zephyrite and Nightstones are actually the two gems from prospecting that I have use for as they are used in jewelcrafting daily quests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carnelians are definitely worth keeping, as you can [transmute them into even more Inferno Rubies](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=80245).

Zephyrite, Jasper, and Nightstone are all used for dailies, so list these on the AH when the appropriate daily is up.

The best use for Alicite and Hessonite, depending on AH prices, is to craft [Alicite Pendants](http://www.wowhead.com/item=52307) and [Hessonite Bands](http://www.wowhead.com/item=52308) for disenchanting.

Alternatively, depending on prices, saving up all your green gems and using them to [transmute to meta gems](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=80237) can also be some good money.

For blue quality gems you're still stuck figuring out which cut will make you the most money and posting them on the AH appropriately.  There's not really a better way than that.